# After updating to Chrome 118 I have lost Authored Sources in Developer Tools

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer-console

I'm not sure about others but I use the Authored vs. Deployed Sources feature of Chrome Tools extensively when debugging Lightning Web Components.

Rather than viewing Deployed (compiled/minified) JS code you can view the original (Authored) source code, which I, personally, find a lot easier to work through and set breakpoints/debug with. For anyone interested you can read more here - https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-104/#authored-deployed

However; after upgrading to Chrome 118 this morning the "Authored" feature seems to have disappeared. It is worth noting that this feature is considered by Google as "experimental" and therefore liable to be unstable, however I've used it without issue for several months now.

I'm just curious is anyone has experienced the same issue and (if you were able to fix it). How? I do have a thread started here - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334670 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be an issue with Salesforce issue now and Content Security Policies?  Just posting in case other Salesforce Developers are experiencing issues with the Authored vs. Deployed feature.

[Report Only] Refused to load manifest from '[URL Redacted]/manifest.json?f345a08ce6028f2543ce95a8bb38961a' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'manifest-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.